# Как проверить прокси на работоспособность?

Tags: python, proxy, urllib

Вот у меня в голове не укладывается, как проверить прокси на работоспособность. Не надо ни проверки анонимности, ни учета времени задержки. 
Надо просто проверить, работает ли прокси или нет. Искал исходники - нашел [примеры](http://r00tsecurity.org/db/code/157/) с использование on-line чекеров, а это не вариант.

Нужен самый простой `ProxyCheker` на `Python`. Наведите на мысль.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю вы о `HTTP` proxy. [Вот обсуждение](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t325113-httplib-and-proxy.html)

> Hi,
>
> thank you all for your help. I tried
> urllib, httplib and sockets.
>
> With urllib:
>
> f =
> urllib.urlopen("http://www.python.org/index.html")
>
> I get:
>
> .... invalid proxy for http:
> 'cache.ilt.fhg.de:81'
>
> httplib works:

```
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("cache.ilt.fhg.de", 81)
conn.request("GET", "http://www.python.org/index.html")
r = conn.getresponse()
print r.status, r.reason
print r.msg
while 1:
data = r.read(1024)
if len(data) < 1024: break
print data
```

> and so do sockets:

```
HOST = 'cache.ilt.fhg.de'
PORT = 81
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
s.send('GET http://www.python.org/index.html HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept:
text/plain\r\n\r\n')
while 1:
data = s.recv(1024)
print data
if len(data) < 1024: break
s.close()
```

> Thanks again

Rolf Wester.